# Cómo colocar y configurar BottomNavigationView en un Fragment

Tags: android, navigationview

estoy colocando un Menu Bottom en un fragment, antes lo tenía configurado en un CordinatorLayout y generaba todo el código desde el MainActivity, pero ahora lo quiero colocar en un fragment y que desde ahi escuche los eventos, lo que necesito es saber como declararlo en el Fragment. A continuación muestro el código xml y el Fragment, tambien les muestro el código que usaba antes en el MainActivity para que me ayuden a pasarlo al Fragmento, muchas gracias.

XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eddd76"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Home">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:background="#eddd76">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/main03"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#202240"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Fragment

```
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

public Fragment_Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__home, container, false);

    return v;
}
}
```

A continuación el código que antes usaba en el MainActivity

```
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

//BOTTON NAVIGATION VIEW

    final Fragment home = new Home();
    final Fragment noticias = new Noticias();
    final Fragment calendario = new Calendario();
    final Fragment ubicacion = new Map_Fragment();
    final Fragment pqrs = new PQRS();
    final Fragment preinscrip = new PreInscripcion();

bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);//Los iconos del menu Bottom toman su color original
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.noticias) {
                //FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, noticias).commit();

            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.rutas) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, ubicacion).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cal_aca) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, calendario).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.pqrs) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, pqrs).commit();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.preinscripcion) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, preinscrip).commit();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });//*
```

Comment: Ya probaste implementarlo? y si lo hiciste que error te dio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en el onViewCreated, si declaras en el onCreateView el view como global.
Ejemplo:

```
private View root;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__home, container, false);

        return root;
    }

 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ...
     bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationViewEx) root.findViewById(R.id.navigation);



...
     // El resto de tu implementación.

    }
```

Si ya lo has intentado y tienes errores, ¿cuales son?

Comment: Muchas gracias, acomodé todo el código en el onViewCreated y ajusté el contexto. ahora quisiera intentar que el menú se oculte como lo hace el menú lateral Drawer, sin embargo aun no tengo la idea clara mientras organizo la idea.